# Unexpected token t in JSON at position 40

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html, css

I am new in angular js. I want to repeat the list using ng-repeat getting content from http. But unfortunately I am getting  Unexpected token t in JSON at position 40.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app="easternApp">
    <body ng-controller="easternController">
         <div class="clearfix blogs" ng-repeat=" item in homelist | orderBy: 'title' | limitTo: 5">
                        <h2>
                            <a href="#" ng-bind="item.title"></a>
                        </h2>
                        <figure><img ng-src="{{ item.imgpath }}" alt="" /></figure>
                        <div class="blogicon clearfix">
                            <div class="blog_collectinfo">
                                <i class="flaticon-small-calendar"></i>
                                <span ng-bind="item.post_date | date: 'medium'"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="blog_collectinfo">
                                <i class="flaticon-chat"></i>
                                <span ng-bind="item.treatments"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="blog_collectinfo">
                                <i class="flaticon-eye"></i>
                                <span ng-bind="item.view"> views</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <article class="blogcontent">
                            <p ng-bind="item.blogcontent | limitTo: 250"></p>
                        </article>
                    </div>
        <script>
            var eastern_app = angular.module('easternApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
            eastern_app.controller("easternController", function($scope, $http, $sce) {
                var homelist_file = "files/homelist_file.json";
                $http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: homelist_file,
                    contentType: "application/json; ",
                    dataType: "json",

                }).then(function(response) {
                    $scope.homelist = response.data.homelist_list;
                });    
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Link of my json file is

```
http://pixperfectionist.in/work/dump/homelist_file.json
```

I am new in angular js. I want to repeat the list using ng-repeat getting content from http. But unfortunately I am getting  Unexpected token t in JSON at position 40. Please help me to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Unexpected token` usually means your JSON is not formatted correctly. Or you are retrieving something that is not actually JSON.

Comment: Hi Kris, Thanks for comment.

Here is my json file.
http://pixperfectionist.in/work/dump/homelist_file.json

Comment: run the json through a validator such as https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, you'll see it's invalid

Comment: Invalid json file, check here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Object property names in JSON must be quoted with `"` characters. Your property names are not quoted.

Comment: So `{ "hello": "world" }` is valid, and `{ hello: "world" }` is not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello friends, Thanks for showing me my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fragment

```
  treatments: 34 + ' treatments',
```

is not a valid JSON value. It's not a string nor a number. It should by just

```
"treatments": "34 treatments",
```

Using online JSON validator is best way to get rid of problems like this.

Comment: If the property names are not quoted, it's **still** invalid JSON.